# How to pass Oauth2 authorization, Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement a shared filespace on an existing server that has its own login/authentication system. I'd prefer if I could use Google Drive or One Drive as the actual backing file store since then the files could (ideally) be edited in browser and automatically update for everyone else that has access to the shared area.

Diagrammatically (red link = existing authorization, red dashed line = desired auth in a session):
[image: Desired Authentication scheme]

The need for this weird scheme stems from usage by a group where almost the entire set of members gets replaced each year (university committee). It was decided we don't just want to use a Google Drive folder since these end up in people's personal Google Drive folders, files get lost of cleared out etc. Additionally we already pass through this website quite regularly so it makes sense as an official repository of committee documents.

However this leaves me stuck with the issue in the diagram. I don't think that the server can create new, temporary tokens for a logged in user for them to pass to the Google Drive API to edit files. The question is really, can I get the Google API to do this for me somehow by only talking to the server? If not, what's the best way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: read about using service accounts. show us a specific issue and code.

Comment: @ZigMandel As far as I could understand, service accounts are used to let an app access users' account data on their behalf. I really want the other way around - users access an app's data. I don't have any code yet, just trying to understand if this is possible at all!

Comment: In other words, is it possible to tell Google that a (possibly not-logged-in-to-google user) is authorized to access a google doc by providing them with some sort of token or otherwise?

Comment: with a service account (or with a reserved admin account) you create the drive doc, so users are never owners.